# Access to value of list

Tags: java, list

I have a problem while reading value of a List. I have this block of code:

```
            Query<User> qr=ds.createQuery(User.class).field("UserID").equal(52005);
            List<User> l=qr.asList();
            Iterator i=l.iterator();
            System.out.println(i.next().toString());
```

I have a list `l` this list is populated with a query on a database (return a record with the UserID 52005). If I print the size of `l` I can see the correct value (1) because there is a UserID with the value of 52005, but my problem is now I cant read the content of this list. If I use the above code I see something else what I expect i.e `Untersuchungsraum.User@88c615`

It seems that it is encoded, `Untersuchungsraum` is the name of the package and `User` is the name of my POJO class.

Here is my Pojo:

```
@Entity("Users")
public class User {
    @Id private String id;
    private String City;
    private int  UserID; 

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.City = City;
    }
...
```

How can I access to value of my list in this sitaution How can I see the City value in the list `l`

Comment: Read up on the `toString()` method or use a getter.

Comment: What do you get that's different from what you expect?

Comment: I should see for example Berlin because this userID belongs to Berlin

Comment: @TangoStar Have you implemented (overriden) `toString()`?

Comment: The whole question has nothing to do with list.  OP should have tried to do a plain `System.out.println(someUser.toString());`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolisHow should I override `tostring()` and why? could you please explain me in detail?

Comment: TangoStar: Please checkmark the answer to this question that has helped you the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `list.get(0).getCity()`

Comment: Thanks if I do so `l.get(0).getCity()` I get `null` as an output, but If I check the size of the list. it has one, that means City should have a value but I cant see the value :(

Comment: @TangoStar It means your zeroth element in the list is `User` and the city is not set for the user, thats why `city` is `null`

Comment: @PrasadKharkar you are right. If I change my code to `l.get(0).getUserID()` I see the value of 52005, but I thought that I write a query but it returns my query as a list

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't the list or iterator, it's how you're handling `User`. When you run:

```
 System.out.println(i.next().toString());
```

it invokes `User#toString()` which is not overridden so it actually invokes `Object#toString`. This gives you that thing. Use:

```
 System.out.println(i.next().getCity());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Query<User> qr=ds.createQuery(User.class).field("UserID").equal(52005);
        List<User> l=qr.asList();
        if(l!=null && l.size()>0){
             User user =  l.get(0);
             System.out.println(user.getCity());
             System.out.println(user.getUserID());

        }
```